# Morally free toposes are free?

Tags: ct.category-theory, topos-theory, categorical-logic

Let $C$ be a category with finite limits. Sometimes people say that $\mathsf{Psh}(C)$ is a *free topos*, and indeed such a name is consistent with the framework of [lex colimits](https://arxiv.org/abs/1107.0778) by *Garner and Lack*, or less ambitiously with the expository paper [Topo-logie](http://mathieu.anel.free.fr/mat/doc/Anel-Joyal-Topo-logie.pdf) by *Anel and Joyal*. All in all, the main properties of such toposes boil down to [Diaconescu's theorem](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Diaconescu%27s%20theorem), $$\mathsf{Topoi}(\mathcal{F},\mathsf{Psh}(C)) \simeq \mathsf{Lex}(C,\mathcal{F}).$$

With this motivation in mind, and for the sake of this question, we define a topos to be *morally free* if and only if the forgetful functor below has a left adjoint (for all toposes $\mathcal{F}$).$$\mathsf{U}: \mathsf{Topoi}(\mathcal{F},\mathcal{E}) \hookrightarrow \mathsf{Lex}(\mathcal{E},\mathcal{F}).$$

It follows from a classical Kan-extension argument that free topoi are morally free. **And it seems reasonable to me that this should correspond to a characterization of free topoi** via some kind of $2$-dimensional Yoneda-like argument. Unfortunately, I do not manage to work it out, that is why I am putting this question on MO.

I should say that this question is mostly led by intellectual curiosity, and I do not think this is a deep question by any means.

**My thoughts**.

- it is reasonable to believe that morally free topoi are [injective topoi](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/injective%20topos), and thus would be totally distributive categories. Following papers like [An Adjoint Characterization of the Category of Sets](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2161031) by  *Rosebrugh and Wood* and the more recent [Totally distributive toposes](https://arxiv.org/abs/1108.4032) by *Lucyshyn-Wright*, this is consistent with our conjecture. If this turns out to be correct, maybe *torsion free* topos might be a more evocative name.
- their category of ($\mathcal{F}$-)points is locally presentable.

Comment: I suspect that Anel and Joyal would define a "free topos" more restrictively, as a synonym of "affine topos" (i.e. $Psh(C)$ where $C$ is itself a free lex category on some other small category $C_0$). I think I'd tend to agree that both "free" and "morally free" are suboptimal terminological choices. For instance, I can't think of another situation where existence of an adjoint is taken to indicate "freeness"...

Comment: More to the point, I believe it follows from the definition that the "morally free" topoi are closed under retracts in the category of topoi, whereas I think that the "free topoi" probably are not. So I don't think the two coincide precisely (but maybe this is the only difference?).

Comment: @TimCampion Yes, AJ would make the choice you suggest but it is not more correct that this one, they just stress on different forgetful functors. One is the forgetful functor from Topoi to Cat. The other from Topoi to Lex.

Comment: @TimCampion your second comment resonates (a lot) with the idea that they are injective topoi, but I couldn't make it entirely work...

Comment: @TimCampion Actually I have the impression that Psh(C) where C may not have finite limits will be morally free, proving the conjecture false, but confirming the weaker conjecture that these are (quasi?-)injective topoi.

Comment: @Ivan : that would be in contradiction with your observation that the categories of points are locally presentable.

Comment: I think these are exactly the injective topos. Following Johnstone in https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BFb0089912.pdf "injective" means that for all geometric morphism $f$, composition with $f^*$ has a right adjoint, and it seems to be you can construct it as composition with $f_*$ followed by the reflection from Lex morphism to cc-lex morphisms. Conversely in the Link above Johnstone show that injective toposes are retract of P(C) for C lex, so if @TimCampion is right that this class is closed under retract this would conclude the proof.

Comment: @SimonHenry I did not have a full proof, but I had the impression that this class is not stable under retract, it is stable under reflective (!) subtopos (in Topoi) (call them adjoint retract, if you prefer), this is similar to an essential subtopos where the additional left adjoint is lex. This is where there might be a connection with Rosebrugh and Wood's work. Concerning the relation to injective topoi, I had come to the same conclusion.